# SVG animation not working in Safari/IE

Tags: css, svg

I have this SVG line animation that draws in a text, however it doesn't seem to work on Safari nor Internet Explorer. IS there something I'm missing?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYgdZv

**CSS**

```
svg path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 4;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-dasharray: 1700;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1700;
  animation: dash 5s ease-out forwards;
   -webkit-animation-name:dash;
  -webkit-animation-duration:5s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-out;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
 -moz-animation: dash 5s ease-out forwards;
  -o-animation: dash 5s ease-out forwards;
  -ms-animation: dash 5s ease-out forwards;

}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS animations, transitions, transforms (as well as `classList` or `dataset` in JS) don't work in IE 11 and older. The transitions/ animations problem [has just been fixed in the Edge engine](https://twitter.com/gregwhitworth/status/567836327183413249) (same goes for `classList`), but for IE11 and older, the only solution is to use JS (SMIL animations don't work either, plus Chrome might drop SMIL as well - **update: SMIL is on its way out, don't use it!**).

This is an example of how you can do it:

```js
var p = document.querySelector('.animate'), 
    offset = 1000;

var offsetMe = function() {
  if(offset < 0) offset = 1000;
  p.style.strokeDashoffset = offset;
  offset--;
  
  requestAnimationFrame(offsetMe);
}

offsetMe();
```

```css
@keyframes fadeInP {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
.animate {
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  /*animation: fadeInP 10s linear infinite;*/
}

/*
CSS animations don't work for this in IE and neither do SMIL animations.
*/
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 400">
 <path stroke-width='8' class="animate" stroke-dasharray="10 10" fill='none' stroke="#000" d="M 0,0 C 100,10 200,80 300,15 " />
</svg>
```

One quick note about your code: always write the unprefixed version of rules last and you don't need `-ms-animation` (IE10+ supports animations unprefixed, while IE9 does not support them at all).

Comment: Good job, It is working with IE but not with Safari any other solution @Ana?

Comment: @MohammedMoustafa No other solution... I can't test in Safari, but I've asked others to do so and they've said it's working...